# GridDB node failed to start

Tags: ssh, nodes, griddb, ssh-config

I attempted to create a cluster in `GridDB` and followed the instructions outlined in the GridDB documentation, which can be accessed through the link: https://docs.griddb.net/architecture/structure-of-griddb/#status-of-cluster. Throughout the process of creating the `nodes` and `cluster`, I encountered no errors.

However, when I attempted to start the nodes, an error occurred stating:

> 4 GridDB Nodes had failed to start. (success: 0 nodes)

Each node produced the following specific error:

> The GridDB node node1 failed to start. (D10203: SSH Connect Error (Node[192.168.0.1:10040, ssh=22], There was a problem while connecting to 192.168.0.1:22)).

You can see the exact errors in the attached screenshot below.
[image: error screenshot]

It appears that there is an error in the SSH connector. I have set all the values to default and used the commands to create clusters with nodes. I specified the `SSH` port number, which is 22 by default. I also provided the IP address and port number of the `GridDB` node. I double-checked the GridDB node's "IP address" and "port number" for connecting the operation control tools in the node definition file of each tool. The IP address is located at

> /system/serviceAddress

and the port number is at

> /system/servicePort

I used exactly the same values in my commands. Despite these efforts, the issue persists, and I am unable to establish the desired output. I would sincerely appreciate any suggestions or assistance you can provide to resolve this matter.